# Get all elements but the first as a separate vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I'm trying to write a basic command-line program in C++. While the rest of the code probably has problems galore, too, the one I'm facing now is this: I've split the inputted line into pieces, but I can't figure out how to get all but the first so I can pass it down the line as the list of arguments for the command.

If this was Ruby, I'd do something like this, where `parts` is the array of space-separated arguments for the command:

```
command = parts[0]
args = parts[1..-1]
```

where `parts` is the array of bits that were space-separated.

**TL;DR**:  How can I get all but the first elements of a `vector`?

If using another type makes it easier, feel free to say as much -- I don't think I'll have *that* much trouble porting it over.

I've tried using a `deque`, but I don't want to modify `parts`, just get pieces of it. I've also searched around on this site, but all of the questions that turn up are either related but solved in a way that I can't use, starts of a really hacky workaround that I'd rather avoid, or totally unrelated.

---

<sup>P.S. I'm not `using namespace std`, but `std::` is a pain to type so I omitted it here. Please do provide it in your answers, where applicable.</sup>

<sup>P.P.S. I'm just (re)starting at C++ so please provide an explanation along with your answer.</sup>

Comment: So you want to remove the first element of the vector? Or do you want to have another vector which has the same elements except the first one? Or do you want to pass a specific range of elements?

Comment: @ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ No, I don't want to remove the element -- I want to get the first element (which is easy; `parts[0]`) and the rest (which I can't figure out). To put it in your words: "another vector which has the same elements except the first one"

Comment: While it's an interesting exercise, you may wish to look up on your platform for a library which will process your command-line arguments for you (such as getopt() on Linux....).

Comment: @Andre Oh, that's all this is: An exercise. I wanna relearn C++, so I'm trying to avoid any non-standard libraries.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> TL;DR: How can I get all but the first elements of a vector?

If you want a vector containing that then do this:

```
std::vector<int> parts = ...;
std::vector<int> args(parts.begin() + 1, parts.end());
```

If you want only to access the vector elements then start from `parts.begin()+1` until `parts.end()`.

Comment: Ooh, I totally missed the constructors in the documentation. I'm gonna try this, and if it works out, accept when it lets me.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this works! I'm gonna put it in my code and pray it works. Thanks for the help :D

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: But don't forget to check that the vector is not empty, or you'll get undefined behaviour.

Comment: better to use `args(std::next(begin(parts), end(parts))` so that it also works with `std::list` and C-arrays (the latter case might need `std::` qualification or using directive).

Comment: @celtschk: Just a clarification for your comment; it'll be UB, because begin() is equal to end() if it's empty, and if you get the next iterator after begin() with begin() + 1, you'll go outside of the iterable range.

Answer (score 4):

The most idiomatic way would be to use iterators and make your function accept an iterator like this:

```
template<typename It>
void func(It begin, It end) { ... }
```

and then you pass your vector as:

```
func(begin(vector) + 1, end(vector));
```

Comment: I wanted a vector because it's easier for me to work with, specifically getting things at specific indices.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes You are still using vectors, you just pass iterators of that vectors instead of the vector itself.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: Vector iterators are random access iterators, therefore they support indices. For example, inside `func` you could access the third element of the subsequence (assuming it exists) using `begin[2]`. Of course that then limits your function to be used on random access interators (vector, deque and array), but that's not necessarily wrong; several standard library functions do that, too. The main difference is that with iterators, you do not copy the elements, but access the elements in the original vector.

Comment: @celtschk Oh, I see! That makes sense. Seems like I need to do some more research.